# How to download sdk api 17 for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am not able to download adt bundle api 17 for phonegap 3.0,

I am configuring Phonegap 3.0 with Android Eclipse,When I am running android from Node.js Command prompt, It is giving error --Please install Android Target 17.Currently I am using ADT bundle SDK 4.3(API 18). In the SDK Manager only API 18 Version is showing.
Please tell me how to update or download API 17 for Phonegap 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com go here and follow their short tutorials for beginner on how to make your first mobile application.

I really really don't suggest you to do any mobile application development for android before you don't read this tutorial.

It wil lteach you how to download everything you need.

Comment: I have read all tutorial and downloaded the Sdk 18 for Phonegap 3.0 but it is giving error when I run adroid Application ---Please install Android SDK 17. While I am using API SDK 18.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your SDK Manager and install 4.2.2 
2) Check manifest  for  android:minSdkVersion=" "
                       android:targetSdkVersion=" "

Hope you will solve it